# How to change the property of a Grid's child dinamically?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a dynamically generated grid, which is populated with data from a database.

```
foreach (Models.Credito c in tabelaVigente.creditos)
{
    Credits_Grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = 35 });

    var RowIndex = tabelaVigente.creditos.IndexOf(c);
    c.Quantidade = 0;

    Image Remove_Button = new Image {
                AutomationId = "Remove_" + RowIndex.ToString(),
                BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Source = "ButtonRemove.png"
            };

    var Number = new Label() {
                AutomationId = "counter_" + RowIndex.ToString(),
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Text = c.Quantidade.ToString()
            };

    var bem_label = new Label() {
                AutomationId = "bem_" + RowIndex.ToString(),
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Text = c.bem,
                TextColor = Color.Black,
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold
            };

    var credito_label = new Label() {
                AutomationId = "credito_" + RowIndex.ToString(),
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Text = _.GetString("Currency") + c.credito.ToString(),
                TextColor = Color.Black,
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold
            };

    var parcela_label = new Label() {
                AutomationId = "parcela_" + RowIndex.ToString(),
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Text = _.GetString("Currency") + c.parcela_100.ToString(),
                TextColor = Color.Black,
                HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold
            };

    Image Add_Button = new Image {
                AutomationId = "Add_" + RowIndex.ToString(),
                BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Source = "ButtonAdd.png"
            };

    // Adiciona os elementos ao Grid
    Credits_Grid.Children.Add(Remove_Button, 0, RowIndex);
    Credits_Grid.Children.Add(Number, 1, RowIndex);
    Credits_Grid.Children.Add(bem_label, 2, RowIndex);
    Credits_Grid.Children.Add(credito_label, 3, RowIndex);
    Credits_Grid.Children.Add(parcela_label, 4, RowIndex);
    Credits_Grid.Children.Add(Add_Button, 5, RowIndex);

    // Adds c to a List
    creditosList.Add(c);

    // Events
    Add_Button.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer(Add_Tapped));
    Remove_Button.GestureRecognizers.Add(new TapGestureRecognizer(Remove_Tapped));
}
```

When the "remove" image is tapped, the amount is decremented.

```
    private void Remove_Tapped(View arg1, object arg2)
    {
        //Gets the Image ID, 
        var nameButton = arg1.AutomationId;

        //converts into a string
        string[] nameSplit = nameButton.Split("_");

        //and gets the index to be updated
        int indexList = Convert.ToInt32(nameSplit[1]);

        //If amount > 0, 
        if(creditosList[indexList].Quantidade > 0)
            //decrements the amount
            creditosList[indexList].Quantidade--;
    }
```

When the "add" image is tapped, the amount is incremented.

```
 private void Add_Tapped(View arg1, object arg2)
    {
        //Gets the Image ID, 
        var nameButton = arg1.AutomationId;

        //converts into a string
        string[] nameSplit = nameButton.Split("_");

        //and gets the index to be updated
        int indexList = Convert.ToInt32(nameSplit[1]);

        //Gets the index of the label I want to change
        int IndexNumber = 0;
        if (indexList == 0)
            IndexNumber = 1;
        else
            IndexNumber = 1 + (indexList - 1) * 6;

        //Increments the amount
        creditosList[indexList].Quantidade++;
    }
```

What I need is to update the label that shows the amount whenever one of these images are tapped.

I've tried accessing the Label's data through the tapped event using `Credits_Grid.Children[IndexNumber]` but I can't change the Text property of the Label.

Comment: it would be much easier to use data binding and then update the model instead of trying to dynamically search through the visual tree to find the control you want

Comment: Hi , welcome to SO ! I have updated an answer for reference . If be helpful ,rememeber to mark it when you have time , thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Data-Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm#interactive-mvvm) with a ViewModel to implement that .

> Data bindings allow properties of two objects to be linked so that a change in one causes a change in the other. This is a very valuable tool, and while data bindings can be defined entirely in code, XAML provides shortcuts and convenience.

Here I creat a sample ViewModel **TapCountModel** to record count of Tap. Here need to add `INotifyPropertyChanged` for ViewModel ,data changed will make the *Xaml* updated when runtime.

```
public class TapCountModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    int tapcount = 0;
    public int TapCount
    {
        set
        {
            if (tapcount != value)
            {
                tapcount = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TapCount");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return tapcount;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

The **Xaml** contains four `Image` and one `Label` .

```
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="Center" />
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="0"
               BackgroundColor="Accent"
               WidthRequest="100"
               HeightRequest="100">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
        <Image Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="1"
               BackgroundColor="Bisque"
               WidthRequest="100"
               HeightRequest="100">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
        <Image Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="0"
               BackgroundColor="Aqua"
               WidthRequest="100"
               HeightRequest="100">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
        <Image Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.Column="1"
               BackgroundColor="Salmon"
               WidthRequest="100"
               HeightRequest="100">
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
        <Label Grid.Row="2"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               FontSize="Large"
               Text="{Binding TapCount}"
               BackgroundColor="Gray"
               HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
               VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>

    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

In **ContentPage** , Bind `TapCountModel` and implement the `TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped` method .

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    TapCountModel tapCountModel;
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tapCountModel = new TapCountModel();
        BindingContext = tapCountModel;
    }

    private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tapCountModel.TapCount++;
    }
}
```

Now will see the effect as follow :

[image]